# Laravel store each one of a comma separated value to another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to store each of a comma separated value to another table , here the input for shipments table:

kloter = 1 ,

fl_date = 2017-10-12,

id_date = 2017-10-12

trackings =  WRT246, RTY6788, YTT665  <--- each of these will be save to shipment_tracking table

**Shipment Model :**

```
class Shipment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['kloter','fl_date','id_date'];

    public function trackings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ShipmentTracking');
    }
}
```

**ShipmentTracking  Model :**

```
class ShipmentTracking extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['shipment_id','track_no'];

     public function shipment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shipment','shipment_id');
    }
}
```

**Here is my controller :**

```
$shipments = new Shipment();

        $shipments->kloter = $request->input('kloter');
        $shipments->fl_date = $request->input('fl_date');
        $shipments->id_date = $request->input('id_date');


        $shipments->save();

        $lastshipment = $shipments->id; // find the last inserted ID

        $trackings  = explode(',', request('trackings')); // explode comma separated values from trackings

        $cnt=count($trackings); // count the numbers of trackings 

        $i=0;

        for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) //iteration

        //i am using raw query
        // code bellow will save the ID of shipment to shipment_tracking,  
        //but i need to change that 9999 value with each values from $trackings
        //i dont know what to put in that '9999'
        {
            DB::table('shipment_trackings')->insert(
                                         array(
                                                'shipment_id'     =>   $lastshipment, 
                                                'track_no'   =>  '9999'            // just a random value
                                         )
                                    );
        }

        // Shipment::find($lastshipment)->trackings()->associate($trackings);



        return back();
```

it is working, but i need to change that '9999' with values from $trackings, any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy bro,

try to replace your `9999` with `$trackings[$i]`

Comment: oh man, should have tried that , i tried $tracking[i]  before..without the dollar sign .... it worked, thanks mate

Comment: Wow, okay bro. Don't forget to mark as correct answer, it will make me happy can help you :D

Comment: i need to wait another 7 minutes to marked it as correct answer..how silly is that ?!! lol